# rsync keeps crashing/freezing

Tags: rsync

So I am moving a clients Wordpress site from GoDaddy to their VPS godaddy server.
and I am using the following command.

```
rsync -azP --ignore-existing --exclude=wp-content/ai1wm-backups XXXXX@DOMAIN:/home/BBBB/html/ /home/XXXX/public_html
```

However I keep getting broken pipes and the Wordpress site has a total of 86GB of data that needs to be transferred according to what I can see.

Is their a better rsync command that will assist is transferring the files I don't want to have to keep re-starting the script.

Note that I am running this command from inside the new server on Godaddy servers.

Comment: You're `rsync`ing through `ssh`. It seems that there's a problem with your ssh session that probably gets killed  or freezes. Try to setup `rsyncd` on the server and rsync from the rsync deamon to see if it works that way.